How to merge range within a range two dataframes
My brain is not braining and I can't figure out how to merge two dataframes for a range within a range. I hope you can help me.
df1 <- data.frame(
  type = rep("A", 6),
  start = c(66, 753, 1436, 2121, 8080, 8982),
  end = c(752, 1435, 2120, 2805, 8972, 9312),
  col1 = c(97.384, 97.23, 97.522, 97.522, 97.522, 97.376),
  col2 = c(686, 682, 684, 684, 892, 330)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  name = c("apple", "apple"),
  start = c(651, 8009),
  end = c(7964, 9314),
  val = c(71298, 1982),
  ave_val = c(9.749487215, 1.518773946)
)

and this is the result I want to get which is a result column that multiplies the cover with the ave_val when it is within the range. Or it can be just the col2 multiple by the ave_val if the range is within the range.



type
start
end
col1
col2
cover
result




A
66
752
97.384
686
101
984.698209


A
753
1435
97.23
682
682
6649.15028


A
1436
2120
97.522
684
684
6668.64925


A
2121
2805
97.522
684
684
6668.64925


A
8080
8972
97.522
892
892
1354.74636


A
8982
9312
97.376
330
330
501.195402



Thank you!

Where does the 101 in column cover come from? There is now cover in your data

Oh the cover column is by only getting the coverage of the range. since df2 starts at 651 while df1 starts at 66, I only took the range within that cover which is 752-651 = 101.

First, use vapply to calculate differences of pmin/pmax on df1 df2 rows, then do the math with help of matrixStats::rowMaxs and max.col.
> p <- vapply(seq_len(nrow(df2)), \(i) {
+   pmin(df1$end, df2[i, ]$end) - pmax(df1$start, df2[i, ]$start)
+ }, numeric(nrow(df1)))
> transform(df1, 
+           cover=(cover <- matrixStats::rowMaxs(p)),
+           result=df2$ave_val[max.col(p)]*cover)
  type start  end   col1 col2 cover    result
1    A    66  752 97.384  686   101  984.6982
2    A   753 1435 97.230  682   682 6649.1503
3    A  1436 2120 97.522  684   684 6668.6493
4    A  2121 2805 97.522  684   684 6668.6493
5    A  8080 8972 97.522  892   892 1354.7464
6    A  8982 9312 97.376  330   330  501.1954


Data:
> df1 |> dput()
structure(list(type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), start = c(66, 
753, 1436, 2121, 8080, 8982), end = c(752, 1435, 2120, 2805, 
8972, 9312), col1 = c(97.384, 97.23, 97.522, 97.522, 97.522, 
97.376), col2 = c(686, 682, 684, 684, 892, 330)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
> df2 |> dput()
structure(list(name = c("apple", "apple"), start = c(651, 8009
), end = c(7964, 9314), val = c(71298, 1982), ave_val = c(9.749487215, 
1.518773946)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


Eyy, this works.
interval_join(df1, df2, by = c("start", "end"), mode = "inner") %>% 
  group_by(start.x, end.x) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  mutate(result = col2*ave_val)

Now, I just have to figure out how to make the cover column
